# Posting from Facebook form to what?

Tags: facebook, html, forms, post

I have made a simple static HTML5 page which I embedded into Facebook page (AKA Facebook application). Now it is just one of the tabs on facebook profile nad you can view it by clicking on it (those who know facebook can see what I think). I have a "Submit" button of a HTML form that sends data "onclick", that is once you fill up a form page you click on submit.

My question, as I never worked with Facebook posting, is **where do I send the data**, is there something like a FACEBOOK hosting or do I need to make my own program that catches the posting event?

Form is used to collect opinions so I need to collect the form data and store it somewhere, but I have a maximal number of messages I can receive.

**P.S. I have only created a Facebook form (static HTML page).HTML is inside Facebook, I used Facebook application called Static HTML that enables to write static HTMl content to your Facebook profile, static HTML has htm5 container, css3 container and js container.**

Comment: If you created a Facebook application you already have your application hosted somewhere... That's where you need to send your data. To your own server.

Comment: I have only created a Facebook form (static HTML page)

Comment: Where is the HTML sitting? Where are the files?

Comment: HTML is inside Facebook, I used Facebook application called Static HTML that enables to write static HTMl content to your Facebook profile, static HTML has htm5 container, css3 container and js container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook itself does not host the applications. It just uses and iframe to make them appear inside a facebook page tab. The applications themselves are hosted by an external server which has to be your case as well. So if you plan to save your custom form data somewhere then the ideal solution is to save them to the same server where you host your application.

In short: yes, you need to make your own program to catch the posting event.